# mysql2 TypeError: f.ClientHandshake is not a constructor

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-rds, mysql2, node-mysql2

I'm trying to use mysql2 to connect to an RDS MySQL instance. When I use the package locally, everything works fine. However, when I use it inside an AWS Lambda function, I get this cryptic error:

```
TypeError: f.ClientHandshake is not a constructor
at new g (/var/task/index.js:275:62824)
at new o (/var/task/index.js:275:224046)
at e.exports.getConnection (/var/task/index.js:275:218705)
at e.exports.execute (/var/task/index.js:275:220197)
at /var/task/index.js:275:372341
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at c.execute (/var/task/index.js:275:372308)
at /var/task/index.js:357:14189
at E (/var/task/index.js:316:24416)
at Generator._invoke (/var/task/index.js:316:24204)
```

Any idea what the issue is? I'm confident that the roles/security groups are all configured correctly.

Comment: GitHub issue https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/issues/890

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Turns out disabling minification in Webpack fixed the issue.

This can be done by updating the `webpack.config.js` to include

```
optimization: {
    // We no not want to minimize our code.
    minimize: false
},
```

Comment: Thank you. This was UNBELIEVABLE. I cannot believe you have to disable minification to get it to work in AWS Lambda. This was 2 hours of my time tonight, gone.